# View files in an SQL Filestream/Filetable through Powerapps

Tags: powerapps

I have developed a PowerApp that enables users to search for an address, view the type of material used in the water line and more. Each water line's sketch (PDF) is stored in SQL using SQL's filestream/filetable functionality.

Is it possible for me to display the sketches (PDFs) for a specific address within the PowerApp?

Comment: Really more of a Powerapp question than SQL. I don't have any issues on the SQL side.